# meaning of はぐった

Tags: grammar, translation, slang

I would really appreciate your help. I just read the sentence

> またひるめしをくいはぐった

and I can't quite figure out what はぐった means and what the basic grammar of this conjugation is. I'm kinda lost...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done some research on the web and はぐった seems to be the past form of 逸る which means "to stray from", "to get lost".

Actually, in your sentence, the verb should have been 逸れる but according to the goo dictionary the meaning of the two verbs tends to overlaps.

So, また昼飯{ひるめし}を食{く}い逸{はぐ}った means "Again, I lost the chance to have lunch."

References :

- [The 逸れる entry in the goo dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/175523/m0u/) (mind the 3rd point)
- [逸る entry in the goo dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/175509/m0u/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%90%E3%82%8B/)

Comment: Wow, that was fast! Thanks a lot, you helped me big time :)